# Android Get Context in a function

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-context

I am a novice, just making my first app, so please excuse my poor phrasing and understanding.

I have made a Class MyAlarms() to help manage my alarm and notification code.  I require context for a few functions, namely Toast, SharedPreferences, and PendingIntent.  GetContext() does not work, nor does getApplicationContext(), so I decided to go with passing the context to MyAlarms(Context context) from the code using it.  This works just fine.

But I have now read that I should not be doing this, as to may lead to memory leak issues.   Is there another way to get context in a class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need the context because you are creating some views? If so, then you need to use .getContext() from whatever layout you are placing that view in.

Comment: I’m not creating views, actually. I’m setting alarms and notifications. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static function, you have to pass in the Context from the Activity in the parameters.

For example:

```
private static void sendMessageToActivity(String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("intentKey");
    intent.putExtra("key", msg);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Change to:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        sendMessageToActivity(this,"test");
    }

    private static void sendMessageToActivity(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("intentKey");
        intent.putExtra("key", msg);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```